# How to Change Site Elements based on referring URL

Tags: php, themes, page-template, child-theme

I want to create WordPress website that changes branding and theme based on the referring URL. We provide white label services to funeral homes and we want to create a generic site where funeral
Customers can choose content and designs with the branding of their funeral home. For example if you visiting genericexamole.com/funeralhomeA would see Funeral Home A’s logo, colours and options and the same for Funeral Home B. We have a large list of clients so we don’t want to run multiple sites for this aspect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done in WordPress using Page Templates.  This allows you to give a unique design for specific pages meeting specific criteria.

There are several methods for assigning page templates to certain pages.  Sounds like for you the easiest would be to create templates based off of the page name (or URL).

So for example, if you create a page with the URL `funeralhomea` you would create a template called `page-funeralhomea.php`.  This `page-pageName.php` structure tells WordPress to automatically assign this template to a PAGE with that URL.

You can read more about [page templates here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/).

The easiest way to get this setup would be to copy your theme and create a child theme, then from there you can copy your child theme's page.php file, rename it to page-funeralhomea.php and make your changes to it.

More info on [creating a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).

This is very common WordPress functionality and there are a ton of resources out there, just google "wordpress page templates" or wordpress how to setup child theme" etc.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here ... changes css/logo etc based on referring url

[Theme / Divi change visitor css and site logo and all site urls based on REQUEST_URI non logged in wp user](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/418399/theme-divi-change-visitor-css-and-site-logo-and-all-site-urls-based-on-request)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/264799)